# Logic operator ! on integer value

Tags: c

I have an question about the ! operator.

If I apply on a integer variable, ex:

```
int i=7;
!i;
return i;
```

The function give me 7, ok;
Before I compiled this code, I was almost sure to be returned 248(negation operator on 00000111 to 11111000).
(I'm using the gcc).

Why Im wrong ? Thanks for the patience !

Comment: Also, `!` is logical negation rather than bitwise, and `int` isn't an unsigned 8-bit quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't save the changed value into variable.
2. '!' is a logical operator not bitwise. It turns true value into false, or reverse.

Integer value 7 is true on logical operation. so if you reverse it, it becomes 0 which means false.

Answer (score 2):

You do not save the result of the operation. The operator returns the result but it does not update the original variable. You need to assign the result back to the variable. And `!` is not the same as `~`. The former is the logical not operator whereas the latter is the bitwise negate operator. It is the latter one that you need.

So `i = ~i` or `return ~i` will do what you intend.

Comment: `~i` would do a 32 bit bitwise not. I think `i ^ 0xff` would be a better suggestion.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Those two are equivalent, given that you type the correct number of `ffff`.

Comment: Yes, but OP expects 248 from 7. So `0xff` would be appropriate right? And not `~`